# Consumir API com Javascript e salvar dados no MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nodemon

Olá,
Atualmente eu tenho uma aplicação que o Backend é em PHP e consome uma API JSON.
Através da consulta eu consigo salvar os dados em meu DB MySQL.
Quero saber se é possível fazer isso em JavaScript.

Segue um exemplo do código que tenho;

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;

class BlingClient {
protected $apikey, $guzzle, $url;

public function __construct($apikey)
{
    $this->apikey   = env('BLING_APIKEY');
    $this->guzzle   = new Client();
    $this->url      = env('BLING_URL', 'https://bling.com.br/Api/v2/');
}

public function filters($arr_filters = [])
{
    $filters = [];

    foreach($arr_filters as $k => $arr)
    {
        $filters[] = $k.'[' . $arr . ']';
    }

    $filters = implode(";", $filters);

    return $filters;
}

public function getPedidos($arr_filters = [], $page = 1)
{
    $filters = $this->filters($arr_filters);

    $res = $this->guzzle->request('GET', $this->url . 'pedidos/page=' . $page . '/json/', [
        'query' => [
            'apikey'    => $this->apikey,
            'filters'   => $filters
        ]
    ]);

    $pedidos = json_decode($res->getBody());

    return (!isset($pedidos->retorno->erros))? $pedidos->retorno->pedidos : [];
}
```

A titulo de aprendizado, quero saber se é  possível fazer isso.

Comment: Você quer saber se dá pra fazer isso no backend com o Node?

Comment: Sim, isso mesmo.
Hoje meu backend está sendo o Laravel e li alguns artigos falando que NoSQL é mais escalável, daí vem a minha dúvida em saber se é possível fazer isso e se sim, como?

Comment: Sim, você pode, mas vale apena refazer todo seu sistema por causa de escabilidade?

Comment: @Costamilam, não irei refazer, é mais para título de aprendizado.

Answer (score 1):

Ao consultar uma API com o Insomnia, tem como solicitar o código para consulta em várias linguagens, como: PHP, Curl, **JavaScript, NodeJS** e entre outras.

Sendo assim, encontrei a resposta para o que eu procurava.

Obrigado

Comment: NodeJS não é uma linnguagem, o Node é aonde roda a linguagem JS